# Check input from user

Tags: java

Aim: Read in the userID, check if the userID has 10-digits and check if it not exists in database, when both right, the program will leave the loop.

This code works on my project, but I think its not the most elegant solution. Have someone any improvements?

**InputReader.java**

```
public class InputReader {

    private String userID;


    public void readInput() throws SQLException {

        boolean UserIDExists = false;
        int existsValue = 0;

        try {

    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.println("UserID (10-digits):");


    while(!UserIDExists) {

        this.userID = input.readLine();

        while (this.userID.length() != 10) {


        System.out
                .println("Input must be 10 digits. Type again: :");
        this.userID = input.readLine();

        }

    CustomerInfo customer = new CustomerInfo();
    existsValue = customer.checkCustomer(this.userID);

    if (existsValue == 1) {

        UserIDExists = false; 
        System.out.println("UserID exists already. Type again:");   

    } else {

        UserIDExists = true;

    }   
    }
```

**CustomerInfo.java**

```
public class CustomerInfo {

    private Connection conn = null;
    private ResultSet resultSet = null;

    public CustomerInfo () {

        try {
                conn = null;
                JDBCConnection jdbcConn = new JDBCConnection(); 
                conn = jdbcConn.openConnection();             

        } catch (Exception e) {
                  throw e;
                } 
        };


        public int checkUserID (String userID) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM TABL0001 WHERE USERID = ?";     
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstmt.setString(1,  userID);
            resultSet = pstmt.executeQuery();


            if (!resultSet.next()){
                return 0;

            }
               return 1;

        }
```

Answer (score 5):

You are using prepared statements which is good, but why does your query return all columns ? A simple `SELECT USERID FROM TABL0001 WHERE USERID = ?` would be enough and if multiple users access this code, the database load would be low which is good.

---

The `checkUserID()` method is returning an `int` which only will be either `0` or `1` and this is **screaming** for a `boolean` which also would simplify the method. Also the name of the method is a little bit  misleading. A better name would be `existUserID`

Like

```
public boolean existUserID (String userID) throws SQLException {

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM TABL0001 WHERE USERID = ?";     

    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pstmt.setString(1,  userID);
    resultSet = pstmt.executeQuery();

    return resultSet.next();
}
```

---

You aren't closing the database connection. Also, because you are  always creating a new `CustomerInfo` you really should make the former `checkUserID()` method static and create the connection there.

If you are using Java 7 or above you should use [try with ressources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to ensure that for any exception that the ressources are closed.

If you are using Java prior version 7 you should use a `finally` block where you the close the ressources.

---

The name `readInput` does not really say much. You should always use meaningfull names for classes, methdos and parameters. Also `readInput` would let me think I would get something back, but no, the method is `void`.

---

> ```
> boolean UserIDExists = false;
> ```

should be named using `camelCase` casing.

---

Instead of `while(!userIDExists)` you should just make `while(true)` and if the userid does not exists just `break;` out of the loop.

```
while (true) {

    this.userID = input.readLine();

    while (this.userID.length() != 10) {


        System.out
                .println("Input must be 10 digits. Type again: :");
        this.userID = input.readLine();

    }

    // assuming existUserId() is static
    if (CustomerInfo.existUserId(this.userId)) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("UserID exists already. Type again:");
}
```

by extracting the reading from the input stream to a separate method this can be simplified some more and will reduce the responsebilities of the method.

```
private String readUserInput(String message) {

    System.out.println(message);

    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));        
    return input.readLine();
}
```

leading to

```
String message = "UserID (10-digits):";
while (true) {

    this.userID = readUserInput(message);

    while (this.userID.length() != 10) {

        this.userID = readUserInput("Input must be 10 digits. Type again: ");

    }

    // assuming existUserId() is static
    if (!CustomerInfo.existUserId(this.userId)) {
        break;
    }
    message = "UserID exists already. Type again:";
}
```

---

Based on the comment I changed the above implementation to break if the userId does not exists. But hey, the variable you formerly used `UserIDExists` is **very very very !! misleading**. One would assume (like I did) if a userId exists then the boolean variable `UserIDExists` would become `true` !

Comment: if (CustomerInfo.existUserId(this.userId)) { , I there you mean:  if (!CustomerInfo.existUserId(this.userId))

Comment: for the method readUserInput, i get the error (Unhandled exception type IOException) , should i add a throws delecaration, or a try/catch  or something elese?

Comment: updated answer regarding `if (CustomerInfo.existUserId)`

Comment: About the exception, which statement should cause this ?